# iOS App crashes when loading Nextpeer Dashboard, uitableview issue apparently

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, nextpeer

In my app, when I call [Nextpeer launchDashboard], the app crashes and I get this error:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:],     
/SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2380.17/UITableView.m:5471
2014-06-23 10:40:07.489 PZPlayer[9966:907] 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception   
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 
'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from   
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
```

I've tried deleting and reinstalling the next peer framework but it didn't help.

Comment: And _are you_ actually returning a `UITableViewCell` or its subclass in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: Nowhere in my app do I use a tableview. It is only when I try to load the nextpeer dashboard through their framework